# Customize button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I wanto to customize a generic button in android, by extendong Button class.

I Simply want that default android button will be displayed with an horizontal line in the middle of the button.

So this is the draw method implementation:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawLine(0, getHeight()/2, getWidth(), getHeight()/2, paint);
}
```

and this is the button inserted in a layout

```
<Button
    class="com.example.backproject.ShadowButton"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</Button>
```

But the button does not change.

Why?

TY in advance!

Comment: Please post your ShadowButton class

Answer (score 2):

You have created customized button then use that like this

```
<com.example.backproject.ShadowButton
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this `<com.example.backproject.ShadowButton` instead of `<Button` in your xml file and remove **class="com.example.backproject.ShadowButton"**
 .

**Edit** : Code

```
<com.example.backproject.ShadowButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: I have an exception.

error inflating class com.example.backproject.ShadowButton

Do I need to add this class to other file?

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to implement a constructor with the AttributeSet because this is the one used by the LayoutInflator: